# Как снизить нагрузку на скрипт при подключении среды WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется cron php скрипт, который выполняет некоторые операции с БД. В этом скрипте я использую такие **wp** функции, как `wp_insert_term()`, `wp_insert_post()`,`wp_cache_flush()` и т.д. `$wpdb` так же используется.

Проблема в том, что на готовом сайте, с кучей установленных плагинов, данный скрипт потребляет намного больше памяти при одном только подключении WordPress.

Вот пример простого подключения:

```
$MEMORY = memory_get_usage();
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../wp-load.php';
echo "Memory: " . (memory_get_usage() - $MEMORY ). PHP_EOL;
```

Результаты:

1. Голый сайт: 34 072 112 байт
2. Загруженный плагинами сайт: 95 157 104 байт

Есть вот такой вот вариант: `define('SHORTINIT', true);`, но он, как я понял, отключает все **wp**-функции, что не подходит.

Соответственно вопрос: я правильно понял, что активированные плагины, пожирают память и если да, то как подключить только необходимые мне **wp**-функции?

Comment: А какие - необходимы?

Comment: @KAGGDesign некоторые `WooCommerce` функции и функции wordpress'a (связанные с постами, attachment, мета и т.д). Их многовато всяких разных. Возможно я не так сформулировал вопрос. Как подключать только ядро wordpressa ?

Comment: Можно написать свой короткий mu-plugin и в нем `add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', '__return_empty_array' );` - так будут отключены все плагины. Если вернуть не пустой массив, а с указанием некоторых плагинов, то будут запущены только эти плагины, например,  woocommerce. Срабатывать mu-plugin должен при наличии константы, которую надо определить перед вызовом wp-load.

Comment: Ядро WP как-то усечь крайне проблематично. Многие функции завязаны друг на друга. Простого способа выбрать те, что нужны, нет.

Comment: Но главное, что непонятно - а к чему все это? Кого в современном мире волнуют жалкие 60МБ памяти?

Comment: Конечно, это может и экономия на спичках, но я только осваиваю Wordpress. И хочется знатькак отключить то, что не нужно.

Comment: Если вопрос носит теоретический характер, тогда другое дело. Мне тоже интересны такие вопросы ради лучшего понимания системы. В целом, мне кажется, я ответил. Плагины можно отключить парой строк кода, а вот части ядра избирательно - вряд ли.

Comment: Спасибо. Ну так же может возникнуть ситуация, когда какой-то активированный плагин может поломать работу скрипта, правильно?

Comment: А деактивация плагина может поломать работу сайта

Comment: А как деактивация плагинов повлияет на работу сайта, если я буду отключать их перед вызовом wp-load в своём скрипте?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73565/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-zhi-v).

Answer (score 0):

> Имеется cron php скрипт, который выполняет некоторые операции с БД.

Сразу 2 ошибки - крон на php и запросы в БД.

1. Во первых если нужен крон, то лучше использовать серверный. А если всё же нужен php, то в ВП есть свой php-крон.
2. В базу лазить нельзя. Тем боле по крону, тем более по стороннему, тем более по стороннему на php.

При работе с ВП нужно использовать [АПИ](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs). В частности для работы с кроном  из ВП - [wp-сron](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cron/), а для работы сторонних приложений с ВП - [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

> Соответственно вопрос: я правильно понял, что активированные плагины,
>   пожирают память и если да, то как подключить только необходимые мне
>   wp-функции?

Нет. Пожирают не "плагины" как таковые, а код. Можно использовать 100500 плагинов без ущерба сайту, а можно в тему прописать 10 строк и положить его при десятке внешних запросов.

В общем, рекомендую посмотреть доклады разработчиков ВП. В них есть и о причинах и о методах/способах локализации проблем.

https://wordpress.tv/2015/08/20/konstantin-kovshenin-wordpress-performance-killers/
https://wordpress.tv/2014/09/02/konstantin-kovshenin-scaling-wordpress/
https://wordpress.tv/2014/08/25/gennady-kovshenin-profiling-wordpress/
https://wordpress.tv/2013/08/19/konstantin-kovshenin-wordpress-site-speed/

> Голый сайт: 34 072 112 байт

Если это показатели на внешней странице, то это ещё и хостинг плохой/не настроен.
Вот на не самом лучшем хостинге реальный сайт без плагинов кеширования и каких-либо серьёзных мер для оптимизации:

[image: а реальном сайте]