# Как импортировать большой объем данных в WooCommerce магазин

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется скрипт, который получает данные из внешнего сервиса и импортирует их в базу данных. Основной код выглядит примерно вот так:

```
foreach ($preparedProducts['create'] as $key => $product) {
    $idProduct = $this->createProduct($product, $brand);
}

private function createProduct($product, $brand)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $item = [
        'post_title' => $product['name'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'product'
    ];
    $postId = wp_insert_post($item);

    $meta_keys = [];
    $meta_keys['_visibility'] = 'visible';
    $meta_keys['_stock_status'] = 'instock';
    $meta_keys['wholesale_customer_wholesale_price'] = $product['wholesale_price'];
    $meta_keys['wholesale_customer_have_wholesale_price'] = $product['have_wholesale_price'];
    $meta_keys['_price'] = $product['price'];
    $meta_keys['_regular_price'] = $product['price'];
    $meta_keys['_weight'] = $product['weight'];
    $meta_keys['_sku'] = $product['sku'];
    $meta_keys['_stock'] = $product['stock_quantity'];
    $meta_keys['_manage_stock'] = 'yes';
    $meta_keys['_id_ds'] = $product['id_ds'];
    $meta_keys['_ean'] = $product['ean'];
    //$meta_keys['_product_attributes'] = maybe_serialize(wp_unslash($product['attributes']));;

    /* SET Attributes */
    $meta_keys['_product_attributes'] = maybe_serialize(wp_unslash($this->createAttributes($postId, $product['attributes'])));
    /* SET Attributes */

    $custom_fields = [];
    $place_holders = [];
    $query_string = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
    foreach($meta_keys as $key => $value) {
        array_push($custom_fields, $postId, $key, $value);
        $place_holders[] = "('%d', '%s', '%s')";
    }
    $query_string .= implode(', ', $place_holders);
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("$query_string ", $custom_fields));

    $this->generateFeaturedImage($product['image'], $postId);

    wp_set_object_terms( $postId, 'simple', 'product_type' );
    wp_set_object_terms($postId, get_term_by('name', $brand->name,'product_cat')->term_id, 'product_cat');

    //update_post_meta($postId, '_product_attributes', $product['attributes']);
    return $postId;
}

private function generateFeaturedImage($imageUrl, $postId, $isCategory = false)
    {
        $imageUrl   = $this->escapefileUrl($imageUrl);
        $uploadDir  = wp_upload_dir();
        $filename   = str_replace("%20", "-", basename($imageUrl));

        if(wp_mkdir_p($uploadDir['path'])) {
            $file = $uploadDir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
        } else {
            $file = $uploadDir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
        }
        file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($imageUrl));

        $fileType = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $fileType['type'],
            'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attachId = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $postId );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attachData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachId, $file );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachId, $attachData );

        if ($isCategory == false ) {
            set_post_thumbnail( $postId, $attachId );
        }
        else {
            update_term_meta($postId, 'thumbnail_id', $attachId);
        }
    }
```

На импорт одного товара на сервере уходит 0.5 - 1.5 секунды, при 10 000 товарах - примерно 2 часа.

Как можно изменить код и увеличить скорость скрипта?

Comment: Мы не ищем лёгких путей? Есть 100500 готовых плагинов для импорта. А скорость зависит и от хостера. Я же [говорил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/789144/233741), что  у тебя плохой

Comment: Помимо - мне нужно так же синхронизировать данные с внешним API со своими особенностями. Плагины здесь не помогут.

Comment: А плагины что - не php код? Помогут. Но помогут это сделать ПРАВИЛЬНО, если брать их в правильных местах, у проверенных разработчиков/производителей. Если сервис с внешним АПИ "особенный", то можно (и нужно)  посмотреть как сделано у других и переписать под себя.

Comment: Ну я не нашёл подходящий. Сможете показать тот, который сможет отправлять запрос на внешний API, сверять продукты на изменение цены, количество, удалять устаревшие, создавать специфичные категории, зависящие от названия группы товаров?

Comment: Вопрос только в получении с внешнего сервиса. Остальное есть во всех, даже бесплатных. Первое видел в каком-то платном.. Возможно что есть и в бесталанных Во всяком случае всегда можно без риска получить данные своим скриптом, сформировать csv/xml/json (это без вмешательство в ВП, а потому почти безопасно) и потом скормить его готовому плагину. Или из готового сделать свой+код для получения данных.

Answer (score 1):

2 часа -это странно. У меня импорт по SOAP выглядел так: скачивание десятков мегабайт по запросу SOAP - порядка 3 минут (но это все зависит от источника), и обработка 14 тысяч товаров с занесением в WooCommerce - около 4 минут. Узкое место - многочисленные запросы к базе при создании и обновлении метаполей. Для оптимизации была написана функция, код которой ниже. Идея в ней та же, что и в вашем коде, за одним исключением - сначала производится чтение метаполей товара, определяются те, которые надо обновить, и только они включаются в запрос INSERT.

```
function update_product_metas( $post_id, $data ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "
            SELECT meta_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id;
            " );
    if ( false === $result ) {
        return false;
    }

    $update_values = '';
    $insert_values = '';

    $count = count( $result );
    foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
        $found = false;
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++ ) {
            if ( $result[ $i ]->meta_key === $key ) {
                $found = true;
                if ( $result[ $i ]->meta_value !== $value ) {
                    if ( '' !== $update_values ) {
                        $update_values .= ', ';
                    }
                    $update_values .= "({$result[$i]->meta_id}, {$post_id}, '{$key}', '{$value}')";
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( ! $found ) {
            if ( '' !== $insert_values ) {
                $insert_values .= ', ';
            }
            $insert_values .= "({$post_id}, '{$key}', '{$value}')";
        }
    }

    if ( '' !== $update_values ) {
        $update_request = "INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
            VALUES {$update_values}
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `meta_value` = VALUES(`meta_value`)";
        $result         = $wpdb->get_results( $update_request );
        if ( false === $result ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if ( '' !== $insert_values ) {
        $insert_request = "INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
            VALUES {$insert_values}";
        $result         = $wpdb->get_results( $insert_request );
        if ( false === $result ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    wp_cache_delete( $post_id, 'post_meta' );

    return true;
}
```

Comment: А картинки на сервер вы не грузите?

Comment: Грузил, но другим кодом

Comment: Отдельно от основного импорта? И как по скорости? Не могли бы вы поделиться ссылкой на тот же gist? Или разница с функцией из моего кода не значительна?

Comment: а нет, посмотрел код - я только добавлял url картинки в товар, а сама картинка оставалась на сайте поставщика

Comment: Вот и разница между нашими скриптами)

Comment: Не факт, надо замерять.